# How do I get my checkboxes to filter together with my select statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select statement and when someone selects a state it returns all the rows with states that match.  I have two checkboxes and they return only rows that match.  I'm not sure how to combine these two functions so that they will listen to each other. I would like my checkbox to further filter the results For instance if you select Texas as your state and then click the textbox Spanish speaking I would like all Texas events that have Spanish Speaking.  If the state is Texas and both Spanish Speaking and Family friendly are checked i'd like all events where state is Texas and both family friendly are checked to return.  I have condensed my code so you can see how both of these work on my table.

```
 <script>
        $("input[name='filterStatus']").change(function () {
          var classes = [];

          $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function () {
              if ($(this).is(":checked")) { classes.push('.' + $(this).val()); }
          });
        
          if (classes == "") { // if no filters selected, show all items
              $("#myTable-events tbody tr").show();
          } else { // otherwise, hide everything...
              $("#myTable-events tbody tr").hide();
          
              $("#myTable-events tr").each(function () {
                  var show = true;
                  var row = $(this);
                  classes.forEach(function (className) {
                    if (row.find('td' + className).html() == `&nbsp;`) { show = false; }
                    else if (row.find('td' + className).html() == `&nbsp;`) { show = false; }
                  });
                  
                  if (show) { row.show(); }
                 });
               }
          });
      </script>
      <!-- End of Checkbox code -->
      <!-- State Dropdown Code -->
      <script>
      $("#filter").change(function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).val();
        var row = $('.row-events');
        console.log(filterValue);
       
        row.hide();
        row.each(function(i, el) {
          if ($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
            $(el).show();
          }
        });

        if ("all" == filterValue) {
            row.show();
        }

        });

      </script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id='label-state-text'>Select Your State:</label>
          <select class="state" id="filter">
            <option value="all" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          </select>
      </form>

 <!-- Checkbox code -->
 <form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="family" />
        <label  for="filter_1">Family Friendly?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="ESP" />
        <label for="filter_2">Spanish Speaking?</label>
      </form>

 <table id="myTable-events">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='event_heading'> Name </th>
<th class='event_heading'> Date </th>
<th class='event_heading'> State </th>
<th class='event_heading'> Family Friendly </th>
<th class='event_heading'> Spanish Speaking </th>    
</tr>
</thead>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
<td> Event 1 </td>
<td> 10/22/2023 </td>
<td> Texas </td>
<td class="family"> Yes </td>
<td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
<td> Event 11 </td>
<td> 10/22/2023 </td>
<td> California </td>
<td class="family"> Yes </td>
<td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
<td> Event 2 </td>
<td> 09/20/2023 </td>
<td> Texas </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="NC">
<td> Event 3 </td>
<td> 06/18/2023 </td>
<td> North Carolina </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="SC">
<td> Event 4 </td>
<td> 05/02/2023 </td>
<td> South Carolina </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP">Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
<td> Event 5 </td>
<td> 12/29/2023 </td>
<td> Texas </td>
<td class="family"> Yes </td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
<td> Event 6 </td>
<td> 11/20/2023 </td>
<td> California </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="AZ">
<td> Event 7 </td>
<td> 08/09/2023 </td>
<td> Arizona </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
<td> Event 8 </td>
<td> 10/19/2023 </td>
<td> Texas </td>
<td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
<td> Event 9 </td>
<td> 08/04/2023 </td>
<td> California </td>
<td class="family"> Yes </td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-events" data-type="AK">
<td> Event 10 </td>
<td> 03/26/2023 </td>
<td> Alaska </td>
<td class="family"> Yes </td>
<td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
</tr>


</table>`
```

I like the way each of these functions work on their own but I can't figure out how to combine them and get them to filter together.

Comment: I was given an answer on this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453434/how-do-i-get-my-checkboxes-to-filter-together-with-my-select-statement

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them like this:

```
$("input[name='filterStatus'], #filter").change(function() {
  var classes = [];
  var filterValue = $("#filter").val();
  var row = $('.row-events');

  $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      classes.push('.' + $(this).val());
    }
  });

  row.hide();
  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if ((classes == "" || classes.some(function(className) {
        return $(el).find('td' + className).html() != `&nbsp;`;
      })) && (filterValue == "all" || $(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue)) {
      $(el).show();
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("input[name='filterStatus'], #filter").change(function() {
  var classes = [];
  var filterValue = $("#filter").val();
  var row = $('.row-events');

  $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      classes.push('.' + $(this).val());
    }
  });

  row.hide();
  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if ((classes == "" || classes.some(function(className) {
        return $(el).find('td' + className).html() != `&nbsp;`;
      })) && (filterValue == "all" || $(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue)) {
      $(el).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id='label-state-text'>Select Your State:</label>
<select class="state" id="filter">
  <option value="all" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
</select>

<!-- Checkbox code -->
<form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="family" />
  <label for="filter_1">Family Friendly?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="ESP" />
  <label for="filter_2">Spanish Speaking?</label>
</form>

<table id="myTable-events">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='event_heading'> Name </th>
      <th class='event_heading'> Date </th>
      <th class='event_heading'> State </th>
      <th class='event_heading'> Family Friendly </th>
      <th class='event_heading'> Spanish Speaking </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
    <td> Event 1 </td>
    <td> 10/22/2023 </td>
    <td> Texas </td>
    <td class="family"> Yes </td>
    <td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
    <td> Event 11 </td>
    <td> 10/22/2023 </td>
    <td> California </td>
    <td class="family"> Yes </td>
    <td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
    <td> Event 2 </td>
    <td> 09/20/2023 </td>
    <td> Texas </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="NC">
    <td> Event 3 </td>
    <td> 06/18/2023 </td>
    <td> North Carolina </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="SC">
    <td> Event 4 </td>
    <td> 05/02/2023 </td>
    <td> South Carolina </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
    <td> Event 5 </td>
    <td> 12/29/2023 </td>
    <td> Texas </td>
    <td class="family"> Yes </td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
    <td> Event 6 </td>
    <td> 11/20/2023 </td>
    <td> California </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="AZ">
    <td> Event 7 </td>
    <td> 08/09/2023 </td>
    <td> Arizona </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="TX">
    <td> Event 8 </td>
    <td> 10/19/2023 </td>
    <td> Texas </td>
    <td class="family">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="CA">
    <td> Event 9 </td>
    <td> 08/04/2023 </td>
    <td> California </td>
    <td class="family"> Yes </td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-events" data-type="AK">
    <td> Event 10 </td>
    <td> 03/26/2023 </td>
    <td> Alaska </td>
    <td class="family"> Yes </td>
    <td class="ESP"> Yes </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: This is further than I was getting, thank you.  I am still trying to get both checkboxes to filter together though too.  This works for one checkbox but now both checkboxes don't work together. I'd like it if both checkboxes are checked that it returns all matching values in the table.  And if it there's a state selected and both checkboxes are checked then I'd like it to take all of that into account.  If that makes sense.  I will continue to look at what you provided too.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @cablank25 how is my solution not working with both checkboxes?

Comment: It doesn't further filter.  So when both checkboxes are checked I'm trying to get the table to display only the rows that have both family friendly and spanish speaking set to yes.  So if both boxes are checked in the code above, and a state isn't selected, we should only see Event 5, Event 9, and Event 10.  If Texas is selected and both checkboxes are checked we should only see Event 5.  Currently the checkboxes don't filter further they just display all events that are family friendly or spanish speaking.